# azure websites got suspended and I cannot see why.

Tags: azure

it doesn't let me look back more than 7 days so I cannot identify why. Could simply leaving the website running cause it to use too much?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your Windows Azure website was running without any problem and your subscription is active, the website must not suspend. I just think there could be some problem as you can not access it and it would be hard to just speculate what went wrong to your Windows Azure Website.

What you need is to contact Windows Azure Websites support team through their online forum as below and provide required info and they will help you immediately: 
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazurewebsitespreview/threads

Answer (score 1):

if the whole subscription is suspended then it is a billing issue most probably. if only the websites are suspended and these websites are on free or shared hosting plan then the websites might have exceeded the CPU quota per the web hosting plan.